# Disable headphone physically in rooted phone

Tags: rooting, hardware, headphone-jack

I want to disable my headphone jack in my rooted Android phone because it is physically damaged. How can I do it? Is there any way in build prp file or any other way so that it is "physically" disabled it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you just choose not to use the headphone jack, will that help?

Comment: I assume the physical damage is causing the phone to think there's something plugged in - preventing speaker audio output - even though there's nothing but air in it.